# Accessing POST variables in Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Using a MEAN stack (MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, and NodeJS) with Mongoose, I'm setting up a simple registration form that will include email address and password fields, among others. I'm including a password confirmation field to ensure users know what they've typed before completing registration. Pretty typical.

However, I can't figure out how to access posted form variables in the model if they're not included in the schema. I don't want to write the password confirmation field's data to the DB, just use it for validation. I have no doubt it's a trivial issue, but everything I've found by searching has used fields included in the schema, which I've got a handle on.

I'm assuming I need to write a schema method, and maybe a virtual, but how do I get to the value of the confirmPassword field? If someone brighter than yours truly would point me in the right direction, I'd be much obliged. Here's what I have so far (note: I omitted other controller methods, dependency declarations, etc. for brevity):

**signup.jade (form)**

```
  form.signup(action="/users", method="post")

    .control-group
      label.control-label(for='email') Email
      .controls
        input#email(type='text', name="email", placeholder='Email', value=user.email)

    .control-group
      label.control-label(for='password') Password
      .controls
        input#password(type='password', name="password", placeholder='Password')

    .control-group
      label.control-label(for='confirmPassword') Confirm Password
      .controls
        input#password(type='password', name="confirmPassword", placeholder='Confirm Password')

    //- Birthdate
    include ../shared/birthdate

    .form-actions
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Sign Up
      &nbsp;
      | or&nbsp;
      a.show-login(href="/login") Log In
```

**users.js (controller)**

```
/**
 * Create user
 */
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var user = new User(req.body);

  user.provider = 'local';
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.render('users/signup', {
        errors: err.errors,
        user: user
      });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
};
```

**user.js (model)**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema,
  crypto = require('crypto'),
  _ = require('underscore');

/**
 * User Schema
 */
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  hashed_password: String,
  salt: String
});

/**
 * Virtuals
 */
UserSchema.virtual('password').set(function(password) {
  this._password = password;
  this.salt = this.makeSalt();
  this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
}).get(function() {
  return this._password;
});

/**
 * Validations
 */
var validatePresenceOf = function(value) {
  return value && value.length;
};

// the below validations only apply if you are signing up traditionally (e.g. not fb, etc)
UserSchema.path('email').validate(function(email) {
  return email.length;
}, 'Email cannot be blank');

UserSchema.path('hashed_password').validate(function(hashed_password) {
  return hashed_password.length;
}, 'Password cannot be blank');


/**
 * Pre-save hook
 */
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (!this.isNew) return next();

  if (!validatePresenceOf(this.password))
    next(new Error('Invalid password'));
  else
    next();
});

/**
 * Methods
 */
UserSchema.methods = {
  /**
   * Authenticate - check if the passwords are the same
   *
   * @param {String} plainText
   * @return {Boolean}
   * @api public
   */
  authenticate: function(plainText) {
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password;
  },

  /**
   * Make salt
   *
   * @return {String}
   * @api public
   */
  makeSalt: function() {
    return Math.round((new Date().valueOf() * Math.random())) + '';
  },

  /**
   * Encrypt password
   *
   * @param {String} password
   * @return {String}
   * @api public
   */
  encryptPassword: function(password) {
    if (!password) return '';
    return crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt).update(password).digest('hex');
  }
};

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I would not try to do that with Mongoose, as it's not about validating the data for the sake of integrity. I would do the 'Do the two entries match' validation firstly on the client side (preferably without reloading the page), and secondly - as a backup - in your controller before doing anything with Mongoose.

Something like this:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  // See if the match fails
  if(req.body.password !== req.body.confirmPassword) {
    return res.render('users/signup', {
      errors: {msg: "Your custom error object"},
      user: {email: req.body.email}
    });
  }
  // Otherwise carry on...
  var user = new User(req.body);
  // etc ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I'm on the fence about where to put my validations. I'm leaning towards the model, since validations are built right into them, according to http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html. It's really bugging me that I can't seem to access posted variables outside of those defined in the schema. I feel like I'm just missing something obvious, and want to uncover this if for no other reason than to just know how to do it. I may ultimately follow your advice, though.

Comment: Well, as it turns-out I was never able to actually do what I originally set out to do - validate everything in the model. I'm sure it can be done, but I'm going to go with Simon's suggestion and validate in the controller. I'm using [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) to do so.